# YouTube-like Ajax Loading Bar not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, youtube, loading

I am using the [YouTube-like Ajax Loading Bar](https://github.com/peachananr/loading-bar) to load a php file.

**This is my Javascript**

```
$(".ajax-call").loadingbar({
  target: "#loadingbar-frame",
  replaceURL: false,
  direction: "right",
  async: true, 
  complete: function(xhr, text) {},
  cache: true,
  error: function(xhr, text, e) {},
  global: true,
  headers: {},
  statusCode: {},
  success: function(data, text, xhr) {},
  dataType: "html",
  done: function(data) {}
});
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<a href="load.php" class="ajax-call">..</a>
<div id="loadingbar-frame"></div>
```

**This is *load.php*, the file that I'm trying to load**

```
<?php
echo 'some content';
?>
```

I'm haven't used ajax before and I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On

```
success: function(data, text, xhr) {},
```

is where you get the response, in this example, data will be equal to "some content", so there you can work with the response, for example replace the content of your html page;

```
success: function (data) {
    $('body').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Is there a way that I could send data using POST to the php file?